# How to create new user at the same time create post in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i have model posts, and now i need this:
If user not authorized on site, create new user model and new post model and deliver for subscribes notification about new post.
I made the following:
create new form on posts/new

```
<% resourse.posts.build %>
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "E-mail" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "password confirmation" %>
           <%= f.fields_for :posts do |form| %>
           <%= form.text_field :title %>
           <%= form.text_field :content %>
      <%= f.submit "Sign up and create post" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

also i add nested attribustes to User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

and create Registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end
etc
```

then i change routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

It's works fine, but i doesn't know how to send subscribers notification via email about new post create on my site?
And how determine posts nested attributes on registration controller like

```
@post = ????
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
        if resource.posts.present?
            @post = resource.posts.first
            flash[:success] = "F#ck off it's all"
            User.includes(:categories, :roles).references(:categories, :roles).where(categories: {id: @post.category_id}, roles: { id: 4 }).pluck(:email).each do |email|
                PostsMailer.delay.deliver_posts_register(email, @post)
            end
        end
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```